# GCM Key for browser apps (with referers) status inactive

Tags: android, status, google-cloud-messaging

I developed an Android app that receives notifications from a web server. I am using GCM (Google Cloud Messaging). Everything was working, I was able to receive notifications almost instantly. Then it stopped working. When I went into the Google API console of my project, I realized that the API key under "Key for browser apps (with referers)" was now showing under Obsolete Key and there was a new API key. The status was set to inactive.

I updated my API key in my project to the new one and now I can receive notifications to my app. It seems like the problem is solved (though the status is still inactive) but I want to know why this happened in the first place and I need to prevent it from happening again.

I would really appreciate it if someone can help me with this.
Thanks!

Comment: I've got the same problem, my key is inactive but the api doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

It is because Google periodically updates its APIs and deprecates older ones.